# Converting Eevee to Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I have a render setup that works great in Eevee but for various reasons I am going to need to get it to look good in Cycles. In areas where there are many triangles it looks grainy in Cycles. In other areas like the one pictured I can see geometric shapes in Cycles' render. See picture. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Also the Cycles rendering seems to take a lot longer (with worse results).

[image: Grainy Cycle's render on left, smooth Eevee render on right]
[image: Cycle's on left, Eevee on right]

Comment: for the triangle artifacts, maybe in the Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry Data > click Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion -- I have an option there to Add Custom Split Normals Data but no option to clear

Comment: ok so it's not the problem